# mastermind game trouble with printing #

Tags: c++

```
#include <iostream>
#include <ctime>


        }
            else if ((array[0]==guess[0]) || (array[0]==guess[1]) || (array[0]==guess[2]) ||(array[0]==guess[3])) {
                cout<<"#";
            }
                else if ((array[1]==guess[0]) || (array[1]==guess[1]) || (array[1]==guess[2]) ||(array[1]==guess[3])) {
                    cout<<"#";                }

            else if ((array[2]==guess[0]) || (array[2]==guess[1]) || (array[2]==guess[2]) ||(array[2]==guess[3])) {
                    cout<<"#";
            }
            else if ((array[3]==guess[0]) || (array[3]==guess[1]) || (array[3]==guess[2]) ||(array[3]==guess[3])) {
                cout<<"#";

            }

        }
}
}
```

This program should print # when one number is not in order.I have attached a photo of instructions.But this program prints # when entered number does not matches the generated number. fdafbbjds fdb fbd f jdsbf b djsbfhsdfbj jdbfjbdhsf hsbdfhb sdjhfhsdbfhjb d hdsfbhdbsfhdsfb dsfj

Comment: And what is the question?

Comment: There's very little text here to allow this question to come up in future searches; and questions showing code not working should show what they do vs what they're expected to do.  Rather than post the instructions; how about point out the specific part that isn't working; what you thought it should do, and what it does?

Comment: Btw. I think I see the problem. If you had enabled your compiler warnings, it would tell you that you do assignment instead of comparison in your later `if`s: `=` -> `==`

Answer (score 1):

In the `else if` statements you're assigning the guess values to the array (You're using `=` instead of `==`).

Also the cases `array[i]==guess[i]` are already checked in the the for-loop, which produces the 'O'. But you repeat the check for these cases in the if-else-statements, which appends an '#' to a correct guess.